# add request to django model method?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm keeping track of a user status on a model. For the model 'Lesson' I have the status 'Finished', 'Learning', 'Viewed'. In a view for a list of models I want to add the user status. What is the best way to do this?

One idea: Adding the `request` to a models method would do the trick. Is that possible?

Edit: I meant in templatecode: `{{ lesson.get_status }}`, with `get_status(self, request)`. Is it possible? It does not work (yet).

Answer (score 2):

If your status is a value that changes, you have to break this into two separate parts.

1. Updating the status.  This must be called in a view function.  The real work, however, belongs in the model.  The view function calls the model method and does the save.
2. Displaying the status.  This is just some string representation of the status.

Model

```
class MyStatefulModel( models.Model ):
    theState = models.CharField( max_length=64 )
    def changeState( self ):
        if theState is None:
            theState= "viewed"
        elif theState is "viewed":
            theState= "learning"
        etc.
```

View Function

```
 def show( request, object_id ):
     object= MyStatefulModel.objects.get( id=object_id )
     object.changeState()
     object.save()
     render_to_response( ... )
```

Template

```
 <p>Your status is {{object.theState}}.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a method to your model with a request paramater:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fields....

    def update_status(self, request):
        make something with the request...
```

Comment: is it possible to call this method from a view? that's the goal and it does not work (yet)!

Comment: You cannot pass arguments to a method from a template.

Comment: Maybe you can try using some template tag.

On template:
{% upd_status status="New Status" %}


on templatetags code:
@register.simple_tag
def upd_status(status):
    ...do something with status

Comment: You can if you use Cheetah templates.

Comment: would be a very nice solution but doesn't work. request is not passed to the save fct